# Can you see HTTPS in curl response?

Tags: http, curl, https

I may be lacking in HTTP and HTTPS knowledge so apologies in advance.

I see that in the response to a curl request, using `curl -i`, we can see the HTTP version and response code, for e.g. `HTTP/2 200`. This is returned when the curl request is directed at a HTTPS endpoint (`https://xxx`).

Would it be possible to see a `HTTPS` in the response? If not, why not?

Comment: curl does have some options to allow it to dump certificate info from the connection (which will obviously only exist if it is HTTPS not HTTP), but it may simply be that curl is the wrong tool for the job. What are you actually looking to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Buffoonism, I want to check if HTTPS is enabled on an endpoint.

Comment: Ah, then I'd recommend you look at the openssl tool (which is available by default on many platforms). So something like ```openssl s_client -connect google.com:443``` will give you a solid answer about whether SSL/TLS is enabled, and lots of information about the details (version of protocol, ciphers, extensions etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, whether the communication is secure or not has nothing to do with which version of the protocol you are using, in the response you will see the version (commonly HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 these days)

Using https means that the connection is established over **TLS**, while the communication protocol is still **HTTP**.

In simple terms, TLS is a communication channel, while HTTP is a dialect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl -v example.com`. It prints out the port number used for the connection. Even though there is no literal mention of HTTPS, you can infer it from port 443.